# Calculate supertrend value in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

How to calculate supertrend value of previous candles in pine script?

For example:

I have to extract super trend value of last 3rd candle

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the supertrend, use the built-in function `ta.supertrend()`.

Then to access the previous values, use the [history reference operator []](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

```
[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(3, 10)
supertrend_previous = supertrend[1]
```